# GTK applications don't get the icon theme selected in KDE

Tags: kde, gtk, icons

I changed my KDE icon theme to [KFaenza](http://kde-look.org/content/show.php/?content=143890) (but it doesn't matter: happens with any other icon theme I choose) and would like to have consistent icons across both KDE applications and GTK applications.

However, no matter which theme I choose, the GTK applications still use another theme (looks like it's Oxygen). For an example of what I mean, look at this picture and compare the first icon in each toolbar (the icon for the *new file* feature of both programs) - the Qt program (top) shows the correct icon, but the GTK (bottom) doesn't:

[image]

This happens even if I use another program (like lxappearance) to set the icon theme manually. I have Fedora 20 with KDE 4.11.4. What to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked around by removing (or, rather, replacing by an empty file) the `/usr/share/themes/oxygen-gtk/gtk-2.0/icons4` file. Then the icons are correct.

Answer (score 0):

You need to select a GTK theme that matches your QT theme. In the system settings app one of the panels deals specifically with the GTK theme (I'm not at home and can't check the exact name). Use this panel to adjust the appearance of GTK applications.